# Firestore rule on uid doesn't work for unknown reason

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an 'owner' field in my documents to entitle only the owner to read the document, and only a new document that its 'owner' field is the uid of the user, can be written:

`allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.owner;`

`allow create, write : if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.owner;`

The creation and update rule works as expected! I tested and saw that if the 'owner' field of the record in the new data is not the user's UID then it doesn't work!

The problem is the 'read' section. I wasn't able to read records. Only when I changed to `allow read: request.auth.uid != null`, I was able to read. 
I triple checked that the records has an 'owner' field that is exactly the same as the UID, also in debug.

I'm have experience with Firebase, and I have no idea what is the problem here.

Comment: "I wasn't able to read records." -> Can you show the code you use to read the documents please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicate that "[You weren't] able to read record**s**" (with an **S** at records), your problem most probably comes from the fact that **security rules are not filters**, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters):

> Once you secure your data and begin to write queries, keep in mind
>   that security rules are not filters. **You cannot write a query for all
>   the documents in a collection and expect Cloud Firestore to return
>   only the documents that the current client has permission to access**.

You don't show the query used to read the Firestore documents, but let's imagine your documents are in a collection named `collection`.

With a query like

```
query = db.collection("collection")
query.get().then(....);
```

you are querying independently of the User ID, hence the problem.

You need to adapt your query with the `where()` method, as follows:

```
//get the value of uid
query = db.collection("cities").where("owner", "==", uid)
query.get().then(....)
```

Comment: Great observation... that was my mistaken assumption. I canceled the filter on the client side to test it out, and assumed that the rules will filter results! Good catch!